# Exchange regenerating calendar cancelation email over and over

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007

Today, at about 9:30am, one of our users deleted a repeating calendar entry from a public calendar on our Exchange 2003 server (using Outlook 2007 on Windows XP).  He chose to have the cancellation sent via email to the meetings 2 attendees.  The calendar event had been repeating weekly since 2007 and was scheduled to continue repeating weekly.  I do not know the end date of the recurring event.

The event has been successfully removed from the calendar, but Exchange is sending groups of 28 meeting cancellation notices every 5-10 minutes to the two attendees.  This has been happening for 2 and a half hours.

I have restarted the Exchange server as well as the user's computer.  There are no outstanding messages in any queue on the Exchange server.  When using the Message Tracking Center tool, you can see that the messages are delivered immediately.  This explains why there is nothing in the queue.  Something is regenerating the cancellation notices every 5 minutes or so and sending them out in batches of 28 emails at a time.

I'm new to this site, but if anyone has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate them!

Comment: Update.  It appears the Exchange server is resending the 28 meeting cancellation notices whenever the user deletes the first 28.  If he doesn't delete the notices, all is good (which is the solution for now).  Still seems weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [poofing the calendar](http://blogs.msdn.com/stephen_griffin/archive/2007/02/21/poof-your-calender-really.aspx)

Comment: Thank you!!!  I did this, which caused me to see some additional occurrences of the deleted entry on the calendar.  Deleted those, and voila!  I can delete the 28 emails and they don't come back.  Thank you!